# Switch off Windows Update for a particular program or feature

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm getting really tired of unchecking the same Windows Update candidates so save hundreds of MB's of dowbloads, especially for programs I never use, that are in fact not even installed, and those I don't wish to update.

Is there any way to permanently, or until another explicit change, to turn off certain updates?  There is an option called 'Hide update', but that unsettles me a bit.

Comment: Why does hiding an update "unsettle" you? There is an option to see hidden updates (from where you can un-hide them) so they are not lost.

Answer (score 2):

> that are in fact not even installed

Can you list examples? As far as I know, if you're using Microsoft Update then it will recommend things like Windows Live Essentials but it will never download them automatically because they're flagged as "Optional".

Windows 7 Ultimate also shows the language packs.

> Is there any way to permanently, or until another explicit change, to turn off certain updates?

Yes, as you have identified you can use 'Hide update'.